# Oracle LISTAGG DISTINCT with multiple conditions

Tags: sql, oracle

For Oracle12, I have the table shown below

| ID | CONTACTCODE | CONTACTPERSON |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | X | CLIENT |
| 1 | X | CLIENT |
| 1 | X | WIFE |
| 1 | Y | CLIENT |
| 1 | Z | WIFE |
| 1 | Z | CLIENT |
| 1 | Z | HUSBAND |
| 1 | W | CLIENT |
| 2 | Y | CHILD |
| 2 | Y | WIFE |
| 2 | Y | CLIENT |
| 3 | Y | HUSBAND |
| 3 | W | CLIENT |

And I want the result like:

- CONTACTPERSON is CLIENT. If CONTACTCODE in (X,Y,Z) then list all distinct CONTACTCODE ( Ex: X,Y,...) else 0 ( MAIN column)
- CONTACTPERSON <> CLIENT. If CONTACTCODE in (X,Y,Z) then list all distinct CONTACTCODE ( Ex: X,Y,...) else 0 ( REF column)

**Expected table:**

| ID | MAIN | REF |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | X,Y, Z | X,Z |
| 2 | Y | Y |
| 3 | 0 | Y |

I used row_number partition by ID, CONTACTCODE and then LISTAGG where row_number = 1 but I had many problems.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `distinct`, `case..when` and `LISTAGG` as follows:

```
select id, 
       coalesce(listagg(case when isclient = 'CLIENT' then contactcode end,',') 
                  within group (order by contactcode), '0') as maincode,
       coalesce(listagg(case when isclient = 'NOT CLIENT' then contactcode end,',') 
                  within group (order by contactcode), '0') as ref 
(select distinct id, contactcode, 
        case when contactperson = 'CLIENT' then 'CLIENT' else 'NOT CLIENT' end as isclient
  from your_table t
 where t.contactcode in ('X', 'Y', 'Z') ) t
 group by id
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `row_number()` and conditional aggregation:

```
select id,
       (case when sum(case when contactperson = 'Client' then 1 else 0 end) > 0
             then listagg(case when seqnum = 1 and contactcode in ('X', 'Y', 'Z')
                               then contactcode
                          end, '') within group (order by contactcode)
        end),
       listagg(case when seqnum = 1 and contactcode in ('X', 'Y', 'Z')
                    then contactcode
               end, '') within group (order by contactcode)
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by id, contactcode order by id) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by id
```

Comment: I think you're missing the end of the 2nd line?